# using no conflict with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to use noconflict in my web site,but i think there is a problem.Here is my code :

```
calling... src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" 
var jQuery_1_7_2 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

(function($){
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
            advanced:{
                updateOnContentResize: true
            },
            scrollButtons: {
                enable: true
            }                                          
        });
    });
})(jQuery_1_7_2);
```

Where am i wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem? what does the console say?

Comment: I've never seen this construction before, putting it in a var. Just calling `jQuery.noConflict();` should work: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: so which jQuery variable is being used by the `mCustomScrollbar` module?

Comment: @Oldskool this usage is documented at the bottom of the link you gave.  It's used to allow some alternate variable to refer to jQuery.

Comment: i am trying to work with jquery 1.3.2 and 1.7.2.Because my image crop part works with 1.3.2 but my special scroll works with 1.7.2.so i have to use both of them with $.noconflict.i think this part is wrong.because my scroll does not work.

Comment: @BahadırYılmaz please also show your `<script>` tags for all jQuery loads and the other modules.  Your problem will be because different modules are seeing different versions of the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note that you're using a plugin `mCustomScrollbar` in your code.

That plugin must be installed in the same jQuery instance as the one in use in your function so it must be loaded *before* you call `.noConflict`.

In practise you'll need something like this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js"> </script>
<script src="module-needing-1.3.2"> </script>
<script>
   var jq132 = jQuery.noconflict(true);  // move jQuery 1.3.2 out of the way
</script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"> </script>
<script src="module-needing-1.7.2"> </script>
<script>
   var jq172 = jQuery.noconflict(false); // leave 1.7.2 as the default...
</script>
```

Comment: Yesss :D i marge my question's second commment and your answer and those solved my problem.Thanks guys.